# Accessing the key in the value (right side) of a table key affectation in Lua

Tags: lua, key-value, lua-table, self-reference

The goal is to match a key of a table with a value depending of the key.

```
example = { ["dummy"] = this .. " example" }
print example.dummy -- print "dummy example"
```

Where `this` is the keyword to refer to the key. Is there any way to do that in Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly.

You could do some preprocessing:

```
example = { ["dummy"] = "{THIS} example" }
for k,v in pairs(example) do
    example[k]=v:gsub("{THIS}",k)
end
print(example.dummy)
```

Comment: Well, it would work for my given example, so that's a relevant answer. However what I had in mind was to using `this` as a parameter of an anonymous function affected to the key, like `example = { ["dummy"] = function(k=this) return k .. " example" end`.

Comment: @psychoslave, in the preprocessing, if `v` is a function, do `example[k]=v(k)`.

Comment: @psychoslave Why not just pass the key directly while calling it?

Comment: I used lhf suggestion, and it works  as expected. You can see the usage on https://github.com/psychoslave/mallupa/blob/7ed0eead4296723ad6600a9b8bee6b99d7f7e7cb/fontaro/mallupe.lua The idea is to tranform flexions of Esperanto roots to some identical tokens in the Lua outputed script. Most of the time the pattern to match return the targeted token. So pattern strings index functions, which most of the time is just the same anonymous function parameterized with the pattern and which itsefl return a function waiting for the token value that, finally, will provide the targeted token.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have as clean an expression as:

```
t = { foo = this .. ' bar' }
```

because `this` would always be expressed without relation to the key or the table. That is, you can't capture an expression as the value of a table entry.

What is possible is implementing some level of indirection using [metatables](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4) and functions, but it's hardly pretty. Here we do fetch-time evaluation. You could also recompute the results.

```
local function indirect_table ()
    local uptable = {}

    return setmetatable({}, {
        __index = function (self, key)
            local value = uptable[key]

            return type(value) == 'function' and uptable[key](key) or value
        end,
        __newindex = function (self, key, value)
            uptable[key] = value
            --[[precompute, with no need for an uptable, or __index:
                `rawset(self, key, value(key)`]]
        end
    })
end

local tab = indirect_table()

tab.foo = function (key) return key .. 'bar' end

print(tab.foo) --> 'foobar'
```

*Note: this example uses a closure, but you can implement this kind of pattern using `getmetatable` as well.*

---

Personally, I'd abstract this into an indirection pattern that allows arbitrary keys and values, and their *actions* to be specified. I figure this kind of pattern would mostly be used programatically, rather than by hand, where the results of key values are dependent on the inputs received. Again, not pretty, but a little more robust (optional actions).

```
local function I (_, value) return value end

local K = setmetatable({
    __call = function (actor, key)
        return actor.action(key, actor.value)
    end
}, {
    __call = function (K, value, action)
        return setmetatable({ value = value, action = action or  I }, K)
    end
})

local T = setmetatable({
    __newindex = function (self, key, value)
        if getmetatable(value) == K then
            value = value(key)
        end

        rawset(self, key, value)
    end
}, { 
    __call = function (T, o)
        return setmetatable(o or {}, T)
    end
})
```

Simple use:

```
local function concat (left, right) return left .. right end

local t = T {}

t.foo = K('bar', concat) -- with a common action
t.zar = K({}, unknown_action) -- without action (`nil`)
t.qux = 'qaz' -- standard

print(t.foo, t.zar, t.qux)
```

---

This is strange metaprogramming. I'd double-check the reasoning for needing such an approach. Perhaps you're falling into an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) trap? Really feels like a solution to a problem that doesn't need to exist in the first place.

Comment: Thank for having taken time to reply with this detailed solution. I gave more context of what my problem was, and how I managed it with the table preprocessing suggested by lhf in a comment to its answer.